# Key stick Dead Battery Buzzing sound

Tags: battery, chevrolet, cobalt

2008 Chevy Cobalt ... Just got done driving the car. Put it in park turned it off. Then tried restarting it right away. It wouldn't start. It started making a buzzing sound. The key was stuck in the ignition. I read about the release under the steering wheel and got the key out. Its still buzzing and when I tried to start it again same thing happened with my key getting stuck. My son takes is drivers test in this on Friday. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried jumping the vehicle? What's the voltage at the battery?

Comment: I'm wondering if the steering lock is placing force on the steering wheel.   This can occur if you are parked on a hill or driveway and there is a bit of load on the system.   If you put the key in the ignition, turn it to accessory (engine off) can you turn the steering wheel, even a little bit (or does it feel stuck?)  Sometimes you can free things up by turning the wheel back and forth a few degrees.